# c# telerik radgridview on update manually update other grid

Tags: winforms, telerik, radgridview

I have a CustomerGrid and a ProjectGrid and in both there is a column ValidUntil.
If I change this column in the CustomerGrid, I want to update the same column in the ProjectGrid.

Is that possible?
Both Grids are bound with DataTables.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the OnNeedDataSource event for binding, you should just be able to call the Rebind method for the other grid.

```
//after updating the database from CustomerGrid data
ProjectGrid.Rebind();
```

Comment: ah, perhaps I didn't make it clear enough, those grids are different database tables.

Comment: Sounds like you need a simple database update on the 2nd database after you've updated the first one.  What's keeping you from doing this?